# Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment "$(this).val() = parseInt($("#x_gen_income").val());"

Tags: javascript

I am getting an error in this line:

```
$(this).val() = parseInt($("#x_gen_income").val());
```

in this block of code:

```
$(this).blur(function(){ 
    if(parseInt($(this).val()) > 10000000){
        alert("WARNING: INCOME IS ABOVE 10,000,00; PLEASE REVIEW THE INPUT");
        $(this).val() = parseInt($("#x_gen_income").val());
        $(this).focus();
    }
    else if(parseInt($(this).val()) == 0){                        
        alert("ERROR: INCOME IS 0, PLEASE REVISE THE INPUT");
        $(this).val('');                                 
        $(this).focus(); 
    }                                                  
    else if(parseInt($(this).val()) < 100000){
        alert("ERROR: INCOME IS LESS THAN 100,000 PLEASE REVISE THE INPUT");
        $(this).val('');                                 
        $(this).focus(); 
    } 
    });
```

The other statements are working fine, can't seem to find what's wrong any help on these? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The left side of a `=` needs to be a valid variable, not a function call. Do this instead:

```
$(this).val(parseInt($("#x_gen_income").val()));
```

Comment: tested it but it loops the alert over and over and over again